# Discord.py bot boost message

Tags: discord.py

Ok, so I want to know how to make a bot send a message to the user who boosted the server. So like for instance somebody boosted the server and the bot sent them a message. The following is an example of what I'm thinking.

```
Client.event()
async def on_boost():
   booster.send(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "MessageType.premium_guild" in str(message.type):
        await message.channel.send("Thanks for server boost")
```

use this

> I left a short message because I am not good at English. I'm sorry if
> I offended you. If you leave a comment, I'll answer it.

Comment: I would like to add a short clarification to this, if you disable the system message when someone boosts, it will not work anymore, since you search for a message type (premium guild subscription in our case) if that is disabled no message will be sent anymore that let the bot know that someone boosted the server

Comment: Maybe, to solve this problem, we can use **on_guild_update**

Answer (score 0):

Normally when someone boosts, a message is put into the discord service channel of a guild. I assume that you can have an `if` statement in an `on_message` event that will trigger if a message is in the format of an boost message + it's author is either the server or `None`

Comment: To clarify a bit: You can check for `message.type in [discord.MessageType.premium_guild_subscription, discord.MessageType.premium_guild_tier_1, discord.MessageType.premium_guild_tier_2, discord.MessageType.premium_guild_tier_3]`, and the booster will be the `message.author`.